More Parallelism Than Expected in Glue ETL Spark Job
I am using Glue ETL Spark jobs to run some tests. I am trying to understand why I am getting more parallel processing than the available cores on a single executor.
Here's my job config:

I setting Glue's "Requested number of workers" to 2 workers for this job. Each worker has 4 CPU and 16 GB RAM - It seems Glue is using one of the workers as Driver and only one for the Executor.

spark.driver.cores=4
spark.executor.cores=4
spark.default.parallelism=4
spark.executor.instances=1



The job itself is doing simple i/o on a list of dataframes:
var dfList: List[DataFrame] = someDfList
dfList.par.map(df => SomeTask.run(someParameter, df)

Now I am testing above config with a list of 10 dataframes. With 4 cores per executor (and 1 total executor available), I anticipated a maximum of 4 parallel tasks to be processed. However, the Spark UI shows a higher number (10).
Is my assumption about parallelism limited by executor cores incorrect? If so, what factors contribute to the actual number of parallel task process in Spark?
More Info from Spark UI


